# Should I create thousands of models (one per user) or a single one?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, statistics

I have application data for a mobile app and I have thousands of users:

Should I create one ML model for each user or a single ML model for the entire application? Here is a cartoonish version of my actual use-case.

Suppose each user can come up with their own color: it can be a typical color (red, blue, green, etc.), or it can be an obscure color, like Aureolin.

For each user session (say, the last 5 minutes of using the application), I would like to predict the most likely color the user will pick (I'll be looking at their previous chosen color, and some other behavioral attributes).

**The rule is: a prediction should only be EITHER one of my 10 globally available colors (the usual ones: red, blue, green, etc.), OR one of the obscure colors that the user had already come up with.**

That is, I should never suggest an obscure color to someone who hasn't come up with it before.

My thinking is that because the space of right answers is more limited than the entire space of answers, each user should have its own model (trained on a subset of the data that includes its own colors and perhaps the global colors as well). If that's the right direction, I'll have to think about coordinating all thousands of models together.

Is this the correct framing?